# Ошибки при запуске эмулятора в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

Всем привет!

Сегодня начал изучать Android.

Установил Android Studio 3.3.2.

Запускаю программу... эмулятор не запускается и выходят вот такие сообщения:

- *Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1*
- *Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!*
- *03/07 14:12:53: Launching app
  Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_XL_API_23 was killed.*

Процессор у меня **Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz**.

Виртуальное устройство выбрал Pixel XL API 23.
Выбрал Marshmallow Android 6.0 x86

Что делать? Спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29136173/1991579

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант вы всегда можете поставить Linux, он бесплатный и лучше подходит для разработки.

Но если вы хотите именно на Windows, существуют и другие эмуляторы, например Genymotion

https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/

или Bliss

https://sourceforge.net/projects/blissos-x86/files/Official/

ну и многие другие, просто загуглите.

Comment: На АВД вообще надежд нет. Потому часто пользуюсь генимоушн, но одельное спасибо за ссылку на Bliss!

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Кликаем Win + X

Заходим в Систему

Смотрим Характеристики Windows. У меня, увы, Домашняя Win 10.

Соответственно, мне нужно ее обновить до Win 10 Pro, чтобы включить Hyper-V (Windows Hypervisor Platform). Она нужна для работы эмулятора.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

https://os-helper.ru/windows-10/kak-vklyuchit-virtualizaciyu-na-pk.html

https://habr.com/ru/post/429610/

Стоит это удовольствие 99$.

**А какую-нибудь стороннюю виртуальную машину нельзя установить для эмулятора Android Studio?**

Comment: С гипервизором оно конечно хорошо, но можно и HAXM'ом обойтись. Вам же дали ссылку - Вы попробовали? Вот на русском: [тык](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows) и решение проблем: [тык](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?tabs=vswin&pivots=windows#hardware-acceleration-issues). Альтернативы есть: Genimotion, сборка Андроида под x86 и отладка на реальном устройстве (лучше всего, но на одном аппарате - одна версия системы, к сожалению)

Comment: А можно просто установить драйвер HAXM из репозитория Android Studio и включить аппаратную виртуализацию в BIOS/ Гипервизор используется для процессоров AMD.